# How could I possibly search a sorted binary tree any faster?

Tags: c++, performance

I am trying to get back into C++, since I hasn't been using it for a year+.

I am trying assignments on this site: www.testdome.com

Currently, my task is to find a value in sorted binary tree. The `Node` class that I am supposed to use looks like this:

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node(int value, Node* left, Node* right)
    {
        this->value = value;
        this->left = left;
        this->right = right;
    }

    int getValue() const
    {
        return value;
    }

    Node* getLeft() const
    {
        return left;
    }

    Node* getRight() const
    {
        return right;
    }

private:
    int value;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};
```

I filled the assignment and came up with two implementations. I get an error for both on the last test: *Time limit exceeded*

I would like to know how could it be written any faster. My implementations:

#### 1. Using `std::stack` to deal with all nodes

I save nested nodes in `std::stack` and go through them until I reach a value. I think this should be the correct solution, avoiding real recursion.

```
bool containsStdStack(const Node& root, int value)
{
    std::stack<const Node*> queue;
    queue.push(&root);

    while(!queue.empty()) {
        const Node*const tmp = queue.top();
        queue.pop();

        if(tmp->getValue() == value) {
            return true;
        }
        // Do not push nulls to avoid extra iterations
        if(const Node* left = tmp->getLeft()) {
            queue.push(left);
        }
        if(const Node* right = tmp->getRight()) {
            queue.push(right);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

#### 2. Naive recursive approach

Since the above failed to pass the performance test, I tried this naive approach - simple solutions often turn out to be faster than expected.

```
bool containsRecursive(const Node&root, int value) {
    return containsRecursive(&root, value);
}
bool containsRecursive(const Node*root, int value) {
    return root!=nullptr &&(
        root->getValue() == value
        || containsRecursive(root->getLeft(), value)
        || containsRecursive(root->getRight(), value)
    );
}
```

But it still doesn't pass the performance test.

**Am I missing something important?** Or maybe the performance test is really harsh? Can this be optimized further without hacks?

Comment: Is the binary tree organised in a sorted fashion? Please provide the exact requirements.

Comment: I am pretty sure the binary tree is expected to be sorted.

Comment: @SergeyA A BST requires sorting.  A generic binary tree need not be sorted

Comment: @NathanOliver I am well aware of this. But the fact that OP's naive approach fails the time test (and generally knowing how those online challenges work) I believe in this case it is (or supposed to be) a BST.

Comment: I agree, @SergeyA, hence my question, but I'd rather the OP (a) thought about it, and (b) clarified it for us as the authoritative source of information.

Comment: The -3 seems a bit much...

Comment: Don't use STL for time/performance critical apps. C++ can't beat the raw speed of C, except for the ease of programming.

Comment: I added the information that the tree is indeed supposed to be sorted. I never noticed it, hence I never thought that it might affect the algorithm. As I said, I haven't been doing this for a while.

Comment: @seccpur This is a C++ test assignment. That does not exclude C usage, but I think it would defeat the purpose if it being specifically C++.

Comment: @seccpur nonsense and heresy.

Comment: True for file I/O to some degree. Largely false otherwise.

Comment: @seccpur Your comment is 1) wrong - STL containers are **the** choice unless you have a good reason to use something more specific, and 2) irrelevant - the OP's problem is, clearly, in the algorithm used.

Comment: STL is perfectly fine to use and is the norm in programming contests, which certainly fall under performance critical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your recursive approach is a good start, but it visits (up to) *every* node when it doesn't have to, given that the tree is sorted.

At each stage, you need only go down *either* the left subtree *or* the right subtree, depending on whether the current node is lesser-than or greater-than the node you're looking for.

So:

- Is the current node a match? Great! You're done.
- Is it too high? Go look down the left subtree (in which everything should be "less")
- Is it too low? Go look down the right subtree (in which everything should be "more")
- Is the subtree we've chosen empty/non-existent? Boo! There is no match anywhere. You're done.

That changes your algorithm from linear to logarithmic, as every good tree search should be. :)

This is why `std::map` uses a less-than comparator to do its work. You can derive equality from this too (for those values for which `x==y => !(x < y) && !(y < x)` holds).

Answer (score 1):

I assume the tree is sorted. Having said that, I am just checking if the value it needs to search on the left or right side of the tree. The search complexity is logarithmic.

```
bool containsRecursive(const Node&root, int value) {
    return containsRecursive(&root, value);
}
bool containsRecursive(const Node*root, int value) {
    // root is null  
    if (root == NULL) return false;

    // value is present at root 
    if(root->getValue()== value) return true;


    // value is greater than root's value //this saves lot of time
    if (root->getValue() < value) 
       return containsRecursive(root->getRight(), value); 

    // value is smaller than root's key 
    return containsRecursive(root->getLeft(), value); 
}
```

Comment: `return root;` Though correct, it took a couple of reads to ensure that this was correct. I would split the `if` into two, returning `false` when root is null and `true` when the key is present. Then it's completely obvious what's happening, and the code should have the same performance (probably even the same translation)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Thank you for noticing. I made necessary changes.